# Numbers with both 3rd and 7th radical integers

Tags: radicals

I was wondering if there are any Numbers where both the 3rd radical and the 7th radical are integers.

For example: 
3rd radical of 125 is 5 (integer) 
7th radical of 125 is 1.9932.. (no integer)

I didn't find any numbers where both radicals are integers. 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try a number $x = a^{3\cdot 7}$, for some integer $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Check 21st powers, such as $1$ or $2097152$ or $10460353203$.